# Why does pyautogui type 7 instead of &

Tags: python, pyautogui

```
import time
time.sleep(10)
time.sleep(1.4)
pyautogui.click(400, 43, 2)

time.sleep(2.4)
pyautogui.write(
    "&"
)
```

Why does pyautogui type 7 instead of "&"
this is the only button i have issues with
May be because of 7 and "&" being the same button
Also i am using mac os
python version used is 3.8.0
Same issue with .press in pyautogui too!
Ive tried command v that works but i need a different solution.
Thanks in advance for the help i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Because it presses the key without shift and ends up pressing 7, so try to press a hotkey which is :

```
pyautogui.hotkey('shift'+'&')
```

**OR**

```
pyautogui.hotkey('shift'+'7')
```

One of these would definitely work now.

> Concept is to press shift first then 7 so it goes to & key.

Comment: that didnt work but this did ```import pyautogui
import time
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.press('&') ```

Comment: Your newest throws a issue. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/husaynjaffer/exampDir/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    pyautogui.write(pyautogui.hotkey('shift'+'7'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 602, in wrapper
    returnVal = wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 1799, in typewrite
    for c in message:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable